# CORS request did not succeed, when deploying MERN stack app in digitalocean

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, cors, digital-ocean

I have two servers running. The react frontend is running on port 3000 and the express backend is running on port 8000. The frontend makes request to the backend, but the request returns CORS error.This problem only occurs on the digital ocean server.

The request from the react app:

```
 await Axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api").then(         
            (response) =>{
                    setListOfArticles(response.data);
                    setIsLoading(false)
            },
                
        )
```

Express backend:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next(); });
```

I have read multiple answers on this topic and tried to change `localhost:8000` with `0.0.0.0:8000`, but with no success.

When adding:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../front/build')))
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../front/build'))
})
```

to the express backend and opening it in the browser the same error occurs.

Do you know why this happens? Note that the app is running flawlessly on my pc.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you are running your front end server on port 3000 unless you do server side rendering. If you are just having a traditional Single page application, you have to build and serve the files through Nginx or even express.

Serve your express app and react app using Nginx. Following link could be helpful.

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-expressjs-and-nginx-29abeef08c67

And you cannot hardcode localhost:8000 into your react app.

```
await axios.get("/api").then(         
            (response) =>{
                    setListOfArticles(response.data);
                    setIsLoading(false)
            },
                
        )
```

Comment: I am using the express server as an api for the app